# Respond to output from a VSCode Task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to respond programmatically to output from a VSCode Task.

As an example:

```js
let task = new vscode.Task(
  { type: 'shell', task: 'run test' },
  'run test',
  'npm',
  new vscode.ShellExecution('npm test')
);
```

Is it possible to trigger a function based on output from Tasks in VSCode?
Alternatively, is it possible run a listener function on the output?

Originally posted as a [VSCode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73315) but closed and diverted to Stack Overflow.